# Calculation of arrival time of messages from 1 source through 2 different routes

Tags: algorithms, normal-distribution, random, poisson-distribution, algorithmic-randomness

I need to simulate sending messages from $A$ to $B$ as follows:

Each message is sent $N$ times from $A$ on the same time, passes through a certain route $R_n$ and arrives at $B$. Travel time of $R_n$ is a random number with a mean of $X_n$ and standard deviation of $Y_n$.

I want to write an algorithm that calculates the possible arrival time of a stream of messages $(t_1, t_2, \dotsc, t_n)$ of messages $1,\dotsc,n$ that are generated with a random rate with a mean of $X_a$ and standard deviation of $Y_a$. I think I should use Poisson distribution here somehow, but having learned this math too long ago I would appreciate if someone can help me to figure out how to calculate this.

For reference - I can easily generate random numbers in Java with Poisson distribution or normal distribution, etc.

Comment: I guess that $R_n$ is suppose to be a random **real** number, right? Since you are talking about a mean a standard deviation and (I suppose) non-discrete times, the normal curve is the first thing that comes to my mind. Either way, you need to add many more details and some context to your question to make it clear what exactly you are asking.